# "options are incompatible" error when running 'stack ghci'

Tags: ghci, haskell-stack

I am running the command `$ stack ghci azara-api:azara-test`, trying to enter the `ghci` repl while importing my tests. (My project name is `azara-api` and my test suite name is `azara-test`.)

```
$ stack ghci azara-api:azara-test
azara-api-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring azara-api-0.1.0.0...
azara-api-0.1.0.0: initial-build-steps (lib + exe)
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded -O0
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: azara-api
Using main module: 1. Package `azara-api' component test:azara-test with main-is file: /home/matthew/backup/azara_work/platform/api/test/Spec.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package azara-api-0.1.0.0
    (use -v for more information)
```

I do not know how to get past this error.
**What does this error mean?**

I am on nixos 17.03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug -
 https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2790 .  Seems trivial I know, but surprisingly tricky to fix due to how things are implemented.

The workaround for now is to either load the library into ghci as well - `stack ghci azara-api:lib azara-api:azara-test`, or probably more easily just `stack ghci --test`.

The other option is to first build the library via `stack build`.  Then `stack ghci` ought to work properly